# Why are there no zip-file (or any archive) conventions?

Tags: archiving

Let me put it bluntly. Should people who do not *put all archived files inside one folder* be deprived of the privilege to reproduce?

## Bad:

```
archive:
    filey
    filez
    fooFolder
    foofolder/moofile
```

## Acceptable:

```
 archive:
     my-archive
        filey
        filez
        fooFolder
        foofolder/moofile
```

Comment: Possibly eligible for closing due to primarily opinion based answers. *sigh*

Comment: If you want to have a opinion based discussion on a topic you are more than welcome to have one over in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), that's what it is there for.

Comment: Because it's easier to mkdir directory;mv downloaded.zip directory prior to unzipping than it is to educate the rest of the planet.

Comment: On Windows almost every archiver has an "extract to folder 'archivename'" option and I for one like that option. It annoys me when people *do* put all the files in a folder and then in an archive.

Comment: Q: Why are there no zip-file (or any archive) conventions? A: Who cares why there aren't? Q: Why don't people all dress the same and have the same haircut? A: Because people are individuals who are free to dress, wear their hair or structure their zip file archives any way they like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the classical reason why you would not want to do this is if you wanted to distribute updates via a .zip file - in that case, the .zip file would be unpacked "directly over" the folder in question and thus you may not want a single top-level folder.

Best practices indicate you should ALWAYS unzip into a temp folder or at least list the archive before blindly unzipping it.